# Multiple Joins causing "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to join three tables in Access and extract one column from each table. I wrote the following query, which I think should work, but keep getting a “syntax error in FROM clause” message. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT A.ONE, B.TWO, C.THREE
FROM (A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ONE=B.ONE)
(LEFT JOIN C ON B.TWO=C.TWO);
```

Thank you.

EDIT: I figured out the problem. There was a paranthesis in the wrong place. I am pasting the proper code below in case someone else also has this issue.

```
SELECT A.ONE, B.TWO, C.THREE
FROM ((A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ONE=B.ONE)
LEFT JOIN C ON B.TWO=C.TWO);
```

OR

```
SELECT A.ONE, B.TWO, C.THREE
FROM (A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ONE=B.ONE)
LEFT JOIN C ON B.TWO=C.TWO;
```

Comment: The rule in access is this: For each join, add one open parenthesis before all the joins and one close parenthesis after the join (including the "ON" clause).

Answer (score 2):

You need the parentheses in a different place:

```
SELECT A.ONE, B.TWO, C.THREE
FROM ((A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ONE=B.ONE)
LEFT JOIN C ON B.TWO=C.TWO);
```

Comment: Voting you up for encouragements - and because of right anwer :-) Mind your formatting and you'll get all thumbs up.

Comment: I'm on my phone so layout is difficult

Comment: These are actually parentheses, not braces. [+1 from me]

Comment: Access requires paranthesis for multiple joins. That being said, the problem was in the paranthesis - one was in the wrong place.